# unable to map keyless json with mantle (properly)

Tags: ios, json, github-mantle

I am trying to find a way to parse my json array properly. I was unable to figure out a good solution to parse my json object using mantle. I was able to find information on parent child objects but not on holding a collection of keyless objects. My code works but it is not an ideal way since there is too much data related code in view controller file. I would appreciate if someone can suggest a better way of doing this( meaning more organized so that I don't have to use a for loop to go over on each item in view controller ).

This is what my json looks like (no keys for the objects in the array):

```
 [
    - {
    id: 40,
    owner: 
    {
    login: “alex",
    id: 9,
    name: “alex",
    avatar: “url here", 
    url: "url ",
    games_url: "url",
    type: "User",
    site_admin: false
    },
    name: “test",
    compliant: false,
    published: false,
    url: “url",
    tags_url:"url",
    subscribers_url: "url",
    cover_url:”url",
    type: “Game"
    },

    {
    id: 40,
    owner: 
    - {
    login: “alex",
    id: 9,
    name: “alex",
    avatar: “url here",
    url: "url ",
    games_url: "url",
    type: "User",
    site_admin: false
    },
    name: “test",
    compliant: false,
    published: false,
    url: “url",
    tags_url:"url",
    subscribers_url: "url",
    cover_url:”url",
    type: “Game"
    },

    {
      more items like this...
    }
 ]
```

this is the code

restmanager.m

```
 - (void)getUserInfo:(void (^)(NSArray *))successBlock failure:(void (^)(NSError *))failureBlock
{
  // gets the data from server via afnetworking and sends it via successblock
}
```

model class

abcmodel.h

```
#import "MTLModel.h"
#import <MTLJSONAdapter.h>

@interface abcmodel : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>

@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString   *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSURL   *coverUrl;

@end
```

abcmodel.m

```
#import "abcmodel.h"
#import <NSValueTransformer+MTLPredefinedTransformerAdditions.h>
#import <MTLValueTransformer.h>

@implementation abcmodel

+ (NSDictionary *)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey
{
    return  @{
              @"name":@"name",
              @"coverUrl":@"coverUrl"
              };
}

@end
```

viewcontroller.m

```
@property ( nonatomic, strong ) NSMutableArray *abcs;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

   [restmanager sharedInstance]fetchData:.....]{
           abcmodel *abcItem;
            for (NSDictionary *abcmodelJSON in responseObject)
            {
                NSError *error;

                abcItem = [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:[abcmodel class]fromJSONDictionary:abcmodelJSON error:&error];

                if (abcItem)
                {
                    [self.abcs addObject:abcItem];

                }else
                {
               //log error
                }

            }

     }

}
```

//and then display it in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is this your entire json file ? Cause this isn't a valid JSON document, you won't be able to parse it

Comment: @Starscream, i changed the json(it is valid) but this is pretty much how it is structured (keyless array collection)

Comment: So what is the problem?  A JSON array translates to an NSArray.  You know what the individual array entries represent -- we don't.